# No read/write access to files owned by root, when using sshfs as root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sshfs

I am using sshfs. I log in as root: `sshfs root@domain.pl:/ /mnt/remotes/domain.pl-root` (using keys). The login process is successful. When I create any file anywhere in `/mnt/remotes/domain-root/`, its owner and group are root. So it seems that I am currently root there, right?

So why can't I read files owned by root that have read and write permissions for the owner (root)? For example, a file like this: `-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 2.0K Jul 17 19:57 some-file.txt` - I can't read it when in the directory mounted by sshfs. However, when I log in "normally" as root via SSH (`ssh root@domain.pl`), I don't have any issues.

Why is that?

Remote OS: Ubuntu 20. Client OS: Ubuntu 22. But I doubt it matters :)